# Button must appear on input focus, but it disappears while clicking another button of the form

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, addeventlistener

I have a problem with a button that appears when an input have focus. "Cancel" button must be visible when a user interact with a search bar. I've made the job done with addEventListener on input click/focus. But there is a problem, when I click "clear" button my "cancel" button disappears on mobile, cause input loses focus. Is there a way to trigger button's appearing on another event suited for my goal? Or may be there is a method to keep focus on input while pressing the "clear" button. Thanks!

I've tried:

- mousedown events,
- addEventListenerAll on all elements of the from,
- changing click to focus and other..

My html

```
<form class="search__form">
<button class="search__cancel" data-search-cancel-appears 
tabindex="0">cancel</button>
<input class="search__input" data-search-cancel-appears type="search">
<button class="search__clear" data-search-cancel-appears tabindex="0">clear</button>
<button class="search__submit" data-search-cancel-appears 
type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```

my css

```
/* clears the 'X' from Internet Explorer */
input[type=search]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=search]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }

/* clears the 'X' from Chrome */
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }
```

my JS

```
const searchCancel = document.querySelector('.search__cancel')
const searchClear = document.querySelector('.search__clear')
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search__input')

searchCancel.style.display = "none"
searchClear.style.display = "none"


searchClear.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
searchInput.value = ""
searchInput.focus()
searchCancel.style.display = ""
searchClear.style.display = "none"
})

searchCancel.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
searchInput.value = ""
searchCancel.click()
searchCancel.style.display = "none"
searchClear.style.display = "none"
})

searchInput.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
searchCancel.style.display = ""
if (searchInput.value.length > 0) {
  searchClear.style.display = ""
} else {
  searchClear.style.display = "none"
}
})

searchInput.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
searchCancel.style.display = ""
if (searchInput.value.length > 0) {
  searchClear.style.display = ""
} else {
  searchClear.style.display = "none"
}
})

searchInput.addEventListener('focusout', function (e) {
console.log(e.relatedTarget)
setTimeout(() => {
if (e.relatedTarget == searchClear) {
  console.log(1)
} else {
  searchCancel.style.display = "none"
}
}, 500)
})


searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
if (event.keyCode === 46) {
event.preventDefault();
if (searchInput.value.length == 0) {
  searchClear.style.display = "none"
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you necessarily need to hide the cancel button on focus lost?

How about hiding it only if the input doesn't have any value, something like this:

```
searchInput.addEventListener('focusout', function (e) {
  if (!searchInput.value) { // trim if needed
    searchCancel.style.display = "none"
  }
});
```

This way even if you click the clear button (triggering focusout) it will not hide the cancel button because at that point the input is not going to be empty.

Comment: OMG! You solved my problem! Thank you so much Mauro!